# GA Event Tracking: Using Google's collect 1x1 not showing up in results

Tags: google-analytics, html-email

Good Day,

I'm trying to include email tracking in my work email via google analytics. I've set up a GA account, and have a unique ID. In my HTML email, I include the following link:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-*MYUNIQUEID*-1&cid=*RANDOMGENNUMBER*&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=*RANDOMGENNUMBER*&cs=pitch&cm=email&cn=trackingtesting
```

where,

*MYUNIQUEID* is my GA id
*RANDOMGENNUMBER* is randomly generated between 0 & 2147483647

Is this the incorrect way to use their link? There isn't an actual website that is linked to this account, just the email tracking.

Thank you!

Zac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, I was looking in the wrong place for the results.

Seems if you set t=event, it doesn't show up in campaigns, only real-time (?). switching to a pageview changes this.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? Are you trying to track clicks on links or email opens, etc..? @ZAR

Comment: @KingOptimizer I did yes. The problem was in the differentiation of an event and a page open. I found it best for emails to count them as page opens, as then it triggers more metrics in GA. But it should be noted that with Page view, one must also include page name. I just used the recipients email address plus subject line as the page opened.